# Como gerar relatório PDF firemonkey android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Preciso gerar um relatório em PDF no firemonkey android, gostaria de sugestões de componentes ou  formas de fazê-lo.

Comment: Indiquei um componente na resposta, de qualquer forma sugiro ao colega ler as regras para publicações de perguntas no *SOpt*. Isso porque, solicitação de sugestões ou perguntas muito genéricas não são o foco do site.  Mas no que precisar (tecnicamente), estamos aí!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma opção que encontrrei é essa.

Uses necessárias

```
Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
Androidapi.JNI.Net,
Androidapi.Helpers,
System.IOUtils,
Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;
```

a procedure que gerar o pdf

```
procedure gerar_pdf;
var
    Document: JPdfDocument;
    PageInfo: JPdfDocument_PageInfo;
    Page: JPdfDocument_Page;
    Canvas: JCanvas;
    Paint: JPaint;
    FileName: string;
    OutputStream: JFileOutputStream;
    Intent: JIntent;
begin

    //cria o documento
    Document := TJPdfDocument.JavaClass.init;

    try

        //cria a página  
        PageInfo := TJPageInfo_Builder.JavaClass.init(100, 150, 1).create;
        Page := Document.startPage(PageInfo);

        Canvas := Page.getCanvas;
        Paint := TJPaint.JavaClass.init;

        Paint.setARGB($FF, 0, 0, $FF);
        Canvas.drawText(StringToJString('Página 1'), 10, 50, Paint);

        Document.finishPage(Page);

        //gera o arquivo  pdf
        FileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, 'arquivo.pdf');
        OutputStream := TJFileOutputStream.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(FileName));

        try
        Document.writeTo(OutputStream);
        finally
            OutputStream.close;
        end;

    finally
        Document.close;
    end;

    // inicia a visualização do pdf
    Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init;
    Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
    Intent.setDataAndType(FileNameToUri(FileName), StringToJString('application/pdf'));
    Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    SharedActivity.StartActivity(Intent);

end;
```

esta função também é necessária

```
function FileNameToUri(const FileName: string): Jnet_Uri;
var
    JavaFile: JFile;
begin
    JavaFile := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(FileName));
    Result := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(JavaFile);
end;
```

No link há um exemplo na prática.

https://github.com/AlessandroMartini/Delphi-Android-GeraPDF

Comment: Recomendo a leitura de [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/5878)

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de se trabalhar com relatórios mobile, é deixar tudo por conta do servidor. Aliás essa é uma boa prática para tudo no mundo mobile.

Sempre que precisar de algo que exija processamento, envia para seu servidor fazer e pegue o retorno pronto.

No caso de relatórios, você pode criar um webservice. Por exemplo:

Monta_Relatorio(data_inicial, data_final)

Você chama esse webservice a partir de seu app... ele monta o relatório, salva em PDF e te devolve uma URL (ex: seusistema.com.br/report?id=2121212) para ser aberto no mobile.

Outro benefício de trabalhar assim é que você não depende da plataforma que o usuário está usando (Android ou iOS)... sempre funciona!

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro o **FastReport**, porque uma versão básica já acompanha o **Delphi** e as versões completas (pagas) são espetaculares.
[FastReport FMX](https://www.fast-report.com/pt/product/fast-report-fmx/)